# R: pivot_wider issue : "Values are not uniquely identified"

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot, tidyverse

My data looks like this:

| item | range |
| --- | --- |
| Item01 | Range 1 |
| Item02 | Range 2 |
| Item03 | Range 2 |
| Item04 | Range 2 |
| Item05 | Range 1 |

I am trying to use the pivot_wider function to expand out the data based on the range column. I use the following code

```
dt %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = range, values_from = item)
```

Which gives me the following warning message:

```
Warning message:
Values are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
* Use `values_fn = list` to suppress this warning.
* Use `values_fn = length` to identify where the duplicates arise
* Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates
```

I am looking for output like this:

| Range 1 | Range 2 |
| --- | --- |
| Item01 | Item02 |
| Item05 | Item03 |
|  | Item04 |

Any suggestions on how to pivot_wider and overcome this issue? Thanks.

Comment: `dt %>% group_by(range) %>% mutate(row = row_number()) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = range, values_from = item)`

Comment: @RonakShah Thank you very much. It solved the issue.